# Help Center subheader pushing first h2 of content-page down

Tags: bug, design, help-center

In the help center when I was just reading up on bounties I noticed this:

[image: On Stack Overflow]

[image: On Meta]

As you can see the top subheader appears to be going under the line and the title is pushed to the right.

I went to check another page suspecting that the cause was because of the longer subheader.

[image: Non-breaking page]

Looking at the developer tools in Chrome the subheader `<div>` goes across fine, but the child `<h1>` and/or `<a>` appear to extend bellow the `<div>`

[image: div hover]

[image: h1 hover]

It is probably nothing major, but I would think there are some certain people who are pulling their hair out about now because I've brought it up and doesn't look right (OCD sufferer? I can't remember the name of the disorder).